# How to check wether or not a value is contained in an array when the value type is ObjectId?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I fetch an array that is stored in mongoose with ObjectIds. After I output this array through the console I get the following output:

> ["5a5f7199105cc908e874d74b","5a5f9199105cc908e874d74b"]

At the same time fetch a different object from mongoose. If I output the ObjectId of this object through the console (object.id) I get the following output:

> 5a5f7199105cc908e874d74b

I try to check whether the value is contained in the array or not. My code looks like this:

> myArray.includes(myObject.id)

and I expect to have the result of true. Unfortunately, I get false as a result even though The value is in the array. Maybe it has to deal with the OBject Type? I really do not know how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: `myArray.includes(myObject.id)`?

Comment: I, of course, had myObject.id in there. Sorry, I forgot to add it in my question.

Comment: I think we need to see more code...

Comment: Is this - object you show us - a normal Array, or some Mongoose wrapper around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in case of Array ["5a5f7199105cc908e874d74b","5a5f9199105cc908e874d74b"] - typeof values is String, so you operate with strings, while when you operate with object property(myObject.id) - you, probably, operate with [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), which is default for latest MongoDBs. Anyway, we need to see your code and know your DB version etc. Easiest way to check is run code "typeof myObject.id", and if you see not "string" - this is an answer to your question.

Comment: I experimented with the type of the Array and the way the id is stored and came to the conclusion that I simply use the .indexOf(myObject) function. That worked for me since this function is casting the same Data type automatically I suppose.